# Chat window issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://demo.rimits.com/rpl/paintball-pole-systemsPaintball.html

Hi !

Kindly refer above link.

I have some chat window opening issue and am thankful if anyone please resolved it.

See, in footer (grey part) there is a heading "Other Info" and under it, there are 2 links, a) live support b) online store. And also these 2 links also displayed on the top of the right column (TRC) under the banner.

so, my issue is, that the chat window code runs for only 1 option, either for footer or for TRC, but I wants that it must runs for both.

thanks
balkar

Comment: Can you post the event listeners you have on these functions?

Comment: you forgot to put function on onClick event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add following code on your live support footer link attribute.
onclick="psAszUow()"